# Doubt on inflection point conditions

Tags: functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

Consider the question:-

Give an example of a function such that:-

1. $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable at $x=a$
2. First derivative of $f(x)$ is $0$ at $x=a$
3. First derivative of $f(x)$ has same sign(positive or negative) on
   both sides of $x=a$
4. $x=a$ is not an inflection point

The first 3 conditions don’t  satisfy all conditions to be an inflection point yet I am unable to find a function to the above conditions.

Please help me in finding such a function. If such a function doesn’t exist, then are the the first 3 conditions enough to declare $x=a$ an inflection point?

Comment: What if first derivative is equal to $0$ on both sides of $x=a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only such function would be $y=c$, where $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is some constant. All the other functions can't possibly satisfy 2nd and 3rd condition without there being an inflection point at $x=a$.